# Truncate Table with Referential Constraint

Tags: java, sql, h2

I have tables "Item" and "Category", where "Item" contains a foreign key constraint that references "Category" (i.e. every item has the name of a category element in its category-column). This constraint is called "CONSTRAINT_74E".

When the data is changed by the user, I need to overwrite the entire database. For this I use the TRUNCATE command. I tried to disable the constraint to truncate CATEGORY:

```
command = "truncate table ITEM;";
s.execute(command); //throws no exception

command = "alter table ITEM disable constraint CONSTRAINT_74E;\n" +
                "truncate table CATEGORY;\n" +
                "alter table ITEM enable constraint CONSTRAINT_74E;";
s.execute(command);
```

This yields the following exception:

> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement
> "ALTER TABLE ITEM DISABLE[*] CONSTRAINT CONSTRAINT_74E; TRUNCATE
> TABLE CATEGORY; ALTER TABLE ITEM ENABLE CONSTRAINT
> CONSTRAINT_74E;"; expected "., ADD, SET, RENAME, DROP, ALTER";
>
> SQL statement: alter table ITEM disable constraint CONSTRAINT_74E;
> truncate table CATEGORY; alter table ITEM enable constraint
> CONSTRAINT_74E; [42001-200]

What exactly do I need to do to make this work? I don't see how I would need to add SET/RENAME/etc. after DISABLE.

Comment: Why don't you just use `delete from item;`? Or actually `delete from category; delete from item;`

Comment: that doesn't reset the id column, right? Would that eventually become a problem with large databases?

Comment: No, it wouldn't. But I find it highly confusing that you always delete the "whole database" (why not just the tables in question?) if the user changes something. Why can't you simply UPDATE the data?

Comment: the database conists of only 4 tables and at the point the DB became a requirement of the project it was much simpler to just implement overwrite instead of observing changes with java.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can't remove data that's being used as a foreign key as that would break referential integrity. You could try to remove the foreign key but adding it again would break if the keys are not the same - and if they are, why are you truncating in the first place?

Depending on your requirements you have a few options here:

- don't truncate but use some other update mechanism (I'd prefer that but I don't know your requirements for truncating in the first place)
- remove the foreign key constraint altogether and deal with missing/wrong keys
- remove the foreign keys (i.e. the values) before truncating and if possible try to reinsert them after new data has been added

**Update:** since you're only asking for the syntax (at least for now), have a look at the [H2 commands documentation](https://www.h2database.com/html/commands.html).

There you'll see that disabling foreign key checks, aka referential integrity, would be done using this command:

```
ALTER TABLE ITEM SET REFERENTIAL_INTEGRITY FALSE
```

It seems as if disabling other constraints is not supported so you might have to drop and add them again.

Btw:

> I don't see how I would need to add SET/RENAME/etc. after DISABLE.

Note that `...expected "., ADD, SET, RENAME, DROP, ALTER";` doesn't mean the statement parser expects the mentioned commands after DISABLE but *instead* of rename, i.e. DISABLE is not supported at this possition (if at all).

Comment: But I already delete the ITEMS containing the referenced foreign keys. Also from what I understand the disable command was meant to disable that exact constraint.

Comment: @Magoni I see, you should add that to your post then so that we have that information.

Comment: @Magoni ah yes I see you truncate ITEMS as well. In that case why do you need to disable the constraint? Truncating CATEGORY should still work because the constrain won't be violated (no foreign keys no violation).

Comment: I have honestly no idea, but when I don't use that I get "org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Cannot truncate "PUBLIC.CATEGORY"; SQL statement:
TRUNCATE TABLE CATEGORY" and then I read that this may be because the constraint is still active.

Comment: @Magoni well, what happens when you try to do that directly in a SQL client?

Comment: Tbh I'm scared to test that. In java, the DB immediately gets filled with the data stored in java objects again, so nothing is lost. If I truncate with the SQL client, I don't have that data stored anywhere.

Comment: Just realized I can just copy the data over from java. when I do it in the SQL client I also get: "Cannot truncate "PUBLIC.CATEGORY"; SQL statement:
TRUNCATE TABLE CATEGORY [90106-200] 90106/90106 "

Comment: @Magoni any other information on the error? And did you try what I wrote in my update?